# Can we set Wordpress archive with 3 month time limit

Tags: wordpress, web, archive, custom-wordpress-pages

How to display the archive widget drop down list as jan- march, april-june like that

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code to get 3 months posts.

```
 <?php 
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'October 1st, 2016',
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2016,
                'month' => 12,
                'day'   => 31,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
```

You need to change month and year as per your requirement.

Comment: Excuse me for the confusion , How to display the archive widget drop down list as jan- march, april-june like that.

Comment: You need to create one widget with dropdown and that selected months post will show on frontend right.?

Comment: now my archive widget drop down display as march 2017, April-2017 like, i need to display as Jan-march 2017, April-June 2017..etc, like

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Put this code in your theme **functions.php** file.

```
<?php
// Creating the widget 
class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
        // Base ID of your widget
        'wpb_widget',
        // Widget name will appear in UI
        __('WPBeginner Widget', 'wpb_widget_domain'),
        // Widget description
        array( 'description' => __( 'Sample widget based on WPBeginner Tutorial', 'wpb_widget_domain' ), ) 
        );
    }
    // Creating widget front-end
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $month = $instance['month'];
        $ex=explode("-",$month);
        // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
        echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        $date = $ex[1];
        $m=date('m', strtotime($date));
        $after=$ex[0].' 1st, 2017';
        $number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, 2017);
        $before=array(
            'year'  => 2017,
            'month' => $m,
            'day'   => $number,
        );
        // This is where you run the code and display the output
        $args = array(
            'post_type' =>"post",
            'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'after'     => "'".$after."'",
                    'before'    => $before,
                    'inclusive' => true,
                ),
            ),
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
        $querys = new WP_Query( $args );
        if($querys->have_posts()):
            while($querys->have_posts()):
                $querys->the_post();
                echo get_the_title()."<br>";
            endwhile;
        endif;
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }       
    // Widget Backend 
    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'New title', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        }
        if(isset($instance[ 'month' ])){
            $month=$instance[ 'month' ];
        }else{
            $month='';
        }
        /// Widget admin form ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('month'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('month'); ?>" class="widefat" style="width:100%;">
                <option value="0">Select Month</option>
                <option <?php selected( $instance['month'], 'january-march'); ?> value="january-march">Jan-Mar</option>
                <option <?php selected( $instance['month'], 'april-june'); ?> value="april-june">April-June</option> 
                <option <?php selected( $instance['month'], 'july-september'); ?> value="july-september">July-Sep.</option>   
                <option <?php selected( $instance['month'], 'october-december'); ?> value="october-december">Oct.-Dec.</option>   
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php 
    }       
    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        $instance['month'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['month'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['month'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
} // Class wpb_widget ends here  ?>
```

Comment: Which part is not working? can you Please describe in more details.

Comment: added this code in function.php and nothing happend

Comment: After adding this code please go to widget area in admin panel. You can see the "WpBeginner Widget" and select that widget and select the month range you want to display.

**Also please change the 'post_type' =>"post" to your post type.**

Answer (score 0):

Use below core function,

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12 ) ); ?>
```

For more reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives

Comment: Excuse me for the confusion , How to display the archive widget drop down list as jan- march, april-june like that.

Comment: Replace which month you want, and just use this code in archive.php and create custom list in widget. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134423/how-to-show-year-month-archive-including-months-with-no-posts